# How to convert form's result to image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

[image]

I'm trying to make an application as in the image.
The user types in the form and the right image is filled with the typed content.
On completion click on "ok" and an image with the result of the form is generated.

I tried to do with the canvas, except that the lines of the texts have different styles, fonts and sizes. I saw that the canvas is very limited to be able to do this kind of customization.

Is there any other way I can do this?

Here is the code I am doing, but it is not completely correct. I'm trying to do it in vue.js

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        titles: [
            { text: 'Title' },
            { text: 'Desc' },
            { text: 'Benef' }
        ],
        contents: [
            { text: 'I am title' },
            { text: 'I am desc' },
            { text: 'Create content here' }
        ]
    },
    directives: {
        insertMessage: function(canvasElement, binding) {
            var ctx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.font = "20px Georgia";
            ctx.fillText(binding.value, 10, 50);
        }
    }
})
```

```css
form { float: left;  margin: 20px 10px;  width: 30%;    }
input { display: block; margin-bottom: 10px  }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="app">
            <canvas width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #BBB;" v-insert-message="contents[0].text + contents[1].text + contents[2].text"></canvas>

            <form class="form-data">
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="" v-for="title in titles">{{title.text}}</label>
                    <input type="text" v-for="content in contents" v-model="content.text">
                </fieldset>
            </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the image need to look different from the form? That is, the image should only be the text from the form inputs?

Comment: The image is different from the form.
I'll stylize the text of the inputs and put a background image.
But the texts need to be stipulated with title and subtitle.

Comment: Can you add what you've tried?

Comment: added in question :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do this in canvas, you would probably have better luck submitting the lines of text to a server and generating your image consistently on the server side (such as with PIL in python or something else). Using canvas is subject to browser support, font support, browser consistency, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the font size / family of the canvas.

```
ctx.font="30px Arial";
```

This will change the font used to Arial, with a size of 30px.

If you want to use a custom font , it must be linked into the document, either by CSS or Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). It actually does exactly what the name suggests. - You pass it some HTML and it will return a canvas which will look exactly the same as the HTML.

You can check out how it works live [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qoWVqM). Simply type in some text and click the button afterwards. The canvas representation of the HTML will be appended. The easiest way to tell that the bottom rectangle is a canvas is by trying to select the text.

This is the source of the live preview:

```
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<p>Actual DOM:</p>
<div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
  <h4 style="color: #000; ">Hello world!</h4>
  <input type="text"></input>
</div>
<button id="go">... to canvas!</button>
<p>Canvas:</p>

<script>
  document.getElementById("go").onclick = function() {
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas)
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is that I have several texts:
title, caption, paragraph.
And I want to stylize each one differently.

Comment: I understand but don't see any problem. Can you post a snippet on codepen or a similar platform?

Comment: I updated my live preview [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qoWVqM) using different styles.

Comment: What do you think about [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WzNjqe)? The `float: left` of the form somehow didn't work. Couldn't find out why yet.

Comment: But I need a result with a totally different style of input form.
=/

Comment: What happens if you style the input the way you want it within the pen? Doesn't it generate the canvas anymore then?